# Jenkins - Trigger parameterized build on other project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

How can I trigger a parameterized build only if the parent finished successfully AND it had changes (changes pushed to scm)?

Here is a scenario: I have 3 builds: A, B and C. 
B will built if it is called by A or it has changes. 
C should be built only if B finished successfully  and if B was built because of scm changes and NOT because it was triggered by A

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

### Add to A:

**Post-build Actions** → **Trigger parameterized build on other projects:**

- Projects to build: `B`
- Trigger when build is: *Complete (always trigger)*
- **Add parameters** → **Predefined parameters:** `A_HAS_BEEN_BUILT=YES`

### Add to B:

**Meta Data** → [✔] This build is parameterized → **Add parameter** → **String parameter:**

- Name: `A_HAS_BEEN_BUILT`
- Default value: `NO`

**Post-build Actions** → **Trigger parameterized build on other projects:**

- Projects to build: `C`
- Trigger when build is: *Stable* [the default anyway]
- **Add parameters** → **Predefined parameters:** `A_HAS_BEEN_BUILT=${A_HAS_BEEN_BUILT}`

### Add to C:

**Meta Data** → [✔] This build is parameterized_ → **Add parameter** → **String parameter:**

- Name: `A_HAS_BEEN_BUILT`
- Default value: `NO`

**Build** → **Add Build step** → **Conditional step (single):**

- Run?: *Not*
- !: *Regular expression match*

  - Expression: `^YES$`
  - Label: `${ENV,var="A_HAS_BEEN_BUILT"}`
- Builder: *... according to your needs ...*

See [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) and [Run Condition Plugin.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin)

#### UPDATE 1

The settings given above induce the following:

1. A builds → B builds → B is stable → C starts, but doesn't build
2. B polls SCM → SCM changes → B builds → B is stable → C builds

According to the discussion the following is intended:

1. A builds → B builds
2. B polls SCM → SCM changes → B builds → B is stable → C builds

#### UPDATE 2

To prevent C from being triggered at 1.:

- Create an upstream project to B that polls the SCM and triggers B
- Configure the following in B:

  **Source Code Management** → ◉ None

  **Build Triggers**

  - [   ] Poll SCM

  **Build** → **Add Build step** → **Conditional step (single):**

  - Run?: *Execute shell / Execute Windows batch command*

    - Command: *... SCM checkout commands; set exit status / ERRORLEVEL greater than 0 in case of no SCM changes ...*
  - Builder: *Trigger/call builds on other projects*

    - Build Triggers

      - Projects to build: `C`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Yes this will work, but I was searching for a solution that won't trigger build 'C' at all...

Comment: @kazerm Why did you write "C should be built ..." then?

Comment: "C should be built only if B finished successfully" - I want to kick a new build of C, but only if there were changes in B. if there were no changes - I don't want C to start and then stop - I want it not to start at all

Comment: @kazerm Then abort B if there are no changes and C will never be started in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain myself well. I always want to build "B" even if there were no changes to it (but it was kicked by build "A"). I just don't always want to build "C" . if B was called by A - don't build C, if B was kicked by push to github, the build C

Comment: @kazerm Does the last paragraph of my update match with what you want?

Comment: yes, this is it: A builds → B builds

B polls SCM → SCM changes → B builds → B is stable → C builds